# Adding composer package to php

Tags: php, composer-php

I am new to composer and I just downloaded a package and where my composer.json is a new folder appeared called vendor which contains my package and a file called autoload.php. Online I read that to access the package contents I have to require the autoload file like this: `require_once "/usr/local/bin/vendor/autoload.php";` however that did not work. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Are you using any framework? And from where you are trying to autoload?

Comment: I am not using any frameworks. The error I am getting is that PHP is not recognizing the classes that came with the package. I am using autoload from inside the vendor folder that got created when I installed my package @MahbubulIslam

Comment: See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to autolod the library in which file you need it like this.

```
<?php

  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

  class YourClass {
      //do something
  }

?>
```

The necessary functions will get loaded automatically as you use them in you `class`.

Keep in mind about `namespace`. For example if you use `stripe` library you need to call it's `retrieve` function like this: `\Stripe\Charge::retrieve($charge_id);`